# HapiJS reply with readable stream

Tags: hapi.js

For one call, I am replying with a huge JSON object which sometimes causes the Node event loop to become blocked. As such, I'm using Big Friendly JSON package to stream JSON instead. My issue is I cannot figure out how to actually reply with the stream

My original code was simply

```
let searchResults = s3Access.getSavedSearch(guid)).Body;
searchResults = JSON.parse(searchResults.toString());
return reply(searchResults);
```

Works great but bogs down on huge payloads
I've tried things like, using the Big Friendly JSON package https://gitlab.com/philbooth/bfj

```
const stream = bfj.streamify(searchResults);
return reply(stream); // according to docs it's a readable stream
```

But then my browser complained about an empty response. I then tried to add the below to the reply, same result.

```
.header('content-encoding', 'json')
.header('Content-Length', stream.length);
```

I also tried `return reply(null, stream);` but that produced a ton of node errors

Is there some other way I need to organize this? My understanding was I could just reply a readable stream and Hapi would take care of it, but the response keeps showing up as empty.

Answer (score -1):

**Did you try to use h.response, here h is reply.**

### Example:

```
handler: async (request, h) => {
    const { limit, sortBy, order } = request.query;
    const queryString = {
      where: { status: 1 },
      limit,
      order: [[sortBy, order]],
    };
    let userList = {};

    try {
      userList = await _getList(User, queryString);
    } catch (e) {
      // throw new Boom(e);
      Boom.badRequest(i18n.__('controllers.user.fetchUser'), e);
    }
    return h.response(userList);
  }
```